# Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist, but it's there in the table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This app displays some data from a database in a TextView.
But whenever I run it, the app crashes due to `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column`_id' does not exist, but the `_id` column exists.
At first, I used `getColumnIndex()`.
After some research I found that `getColumnIndexOrThrow()` would solve my problem but I'm not able to understand why it says column `_id` does not exist.

Is there something I missed which is causing this error?

```
    private void displayDatabaseInfo() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {
            petsEntry.COLUMN_ID,
            petsEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
            petsEntry.COLUMN_BREED,
            petsEntry.COLUMN_GENDER,
            petsEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT };

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            petsEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    TextView displayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_pet);

    try {
        displayView.setText("The pets table contains " + cursor.getCount() + " pets.\n\n");
        displayView.append(petsEntry.COLUMN_ID + " - " +
                petsEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " - " +
                petsEntry.COLUMN_BREED + " - " +
                petsEntry.COLUMN_GENDER + " - " +
                petsEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT + "\n");

        //Error occurs at this line, The column becomes invisible from here
        int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(petsEntry.COLUMN_ID);
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(petsEntry.COLUMN_NAME);
        int breedColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(petsEntry.COLUMN_BREED);
        int genderColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(petsEntry.COLUMN_GENDER);
        int weightColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(petsEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                int currentID = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
                String currentName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
                String currentBreed = cursor.getString(breedColumnIndex);
                int currentGender = cursor.getInt(genderColumnIndex);
                int currentWeight = cursor.getInt(weightColumnIndex);

                displayView.append(("\n" + currentID + " - " +
                        currentName + " - " +
                        currentBreed + " - " +
                        currentGender + " - " +
                        currentWeight));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

PetDBHelper.java

```
public class PetDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String LOG_TAG = PetDBHelper.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pets.db";
private static final String SQL_EXECUTE = "CREATE TABLE " + petsEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
        petsEntry.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        petsEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        petsEntry.COLUMN_BREED + " TEXT, " +
        petsEntry.COLUMN_GENDER + " INTEGER, " +
        petsEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT + " INTEGER );";

public PetDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_EXECUTE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

Comment: You probably added the `_id` column after a first test launch. Uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: No success, still stays the same. i removed the column _id to check whether it displays other columns but it's telling column ' name ' does not exist.

Comment: yes i unistalled and reinstalled the app

Comment: Can you post your db helper class ?

Comment: @AbhishekJain Done